# Was the Shimei mentioned in 1 Kings 1 the same Shimei who cursed David?

Tags: 1-kings

1 Kings 1:7-8 (NIV):

> 7 Adonijah conferred with Joab son of Zeruiah and with Abiathar the priest, and they gave him their support. 8 But Zadok the priest, Benaiah son of Jehoiada, Nathan the prophet, **Shimei** and Rei and David’s special guard did not join Adonijah.

Who, exactly, is Shimei here? Is he the same Shimei who cursed David when he fled from Absalom? If so, why does he now appear to be an important figure to David?

In either case, why was it a big deal that Shimei was not with Adonijah? I understand why Zadok, Nathan, and David's personal guard were important, but why was it noteworthy that Shimei wasn't with them?

Answer (score 1):

There were many people in Israel named "Shimei" as listed in BDB.  I strongly suspect that the man in 1 Kings 1:8 and that in 2 Sam 16:5-14, 19:18, 19, etc, are different people.  The listing in BDB suggests this as seen below.

> I. שִׁמְעִי43 proper name, masculine usually Σευεει: 1 in Benjamin:
>
> a. 2 Samuel 16:5,7,13; 2 Samuel 19:17; 2 Samuel 19:19; 2 Samuel 19:22;
> 2 Samuel 19:24, 1 Kings 2:8 10t. 1Kings 2..
>
> b. 1 Kings 1:8, perhaps = 1 Kings 4:18.
>
> 2 a Ramathite 1 Chronicles 27:27.
>
> 3 Levites: a. 'son' of Gershon Exodus 6:17; Numbers 3:18; 1 Chronicles
> 6:2; 1 Chronicles 23:7,9,10 (twice in verse)
>
> b. 1 Chronicles 6:14.
>
> c. v.1 Chronicles 6:27.
>
> d 1 Chronicles 25:17.
>
> e.2Chronicles 29:14.
>
> f.2Chronicles 31:12,13.
>
> g. Ezra 10:23.
>
> 4 brother of Zerubbabel 1 Chronicles 3:19.
>
> 5 in Simeon 1 Chronicles 4:26,27.
>
> 6 in Reuben 1 Chronicles 5:4.
>
> 7 1 Chronicles 8:13 #NAME?שֶׁמַע 1 Chronicles 8:13.
>
> 8 post-exilic names:
>
> a. Ezra 10:33.
>
> b. Ezra 10:38 (compare 3g above).
>
> 9 grandfather of Mordecai Esther 2:5.
>
> 10 2 Samuel 21:21 Kt (Qr שִׁמְעָא q. v. 1).

Comment: Good point. Out of curiosity, are there any clues as to why would the author of the text considered it noteworthy that Shimei didn't join the conspiracy? Does that give us a hint as to which Shimei they're talking about?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - According to the above list in BDB, the Shimei of 1 Kings 1:8 (and possibly 4:18) suggests that he was a very senior official in David's bureaucracy.  Hence his listing in who sided with whom.

Answer (score 1):

Was the Shimei mentioned in 1 Kings 1 the same Shimei who cursed David?

No, Solomon ordered the execution of Shimei the son of Gera who cursed David.

1 Kings 2:44 The king also said to Shimei, “You know in your heart all the wrong you did to my father David. Now the Lord will repay you for your wrongdoing. 45But King Solomon will be blessed, and David’s throne will remain secure before the Lord forever.”

46Then the king gave the order to Benaiah son of Jehoiada, and he went out and struck Shimei down and he died.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your answer.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.